# Borrar archivos en distintas ubicaciones

Tags: bash

Estoy haciendo un script que me hace un respaldo diario y se copia a su respectiva carpeta dentro de una llamada "respaldos", sin embargo necesito que también se comprueben cuantos archivos tengo en el directorio destino, que no deberían ser mas de 30, y hacer lo mismo por cada directorio dentro de "respaldos"... estoy atascado en la parte en que entro a borrar archivos directorio por directorio y me quedo solo con 30 archivos, alguien me echa una mano?? aquí es donde tengo el problema:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls respaldos/ | while read folder;
do
    count=($(ls respaldos/${folder} | wc -l))
    while [ ${count} -gt "30" ];
    do
        cd respaldos/${folder};
        ls -t | tail -1 | xargs rm
        ((count--));
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un *command substitution* sobre la diferencia entre la cantidad de encontrados y la cantidad de permitidos.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -ri _cant_respaldos_permitidos=30
declare -r _resp_dir=/tmp/respaldos # Cambia el directorio que quieras

for carpeta in $_resp_dir/* ;do
    
    declare -i _cant_respaldos=$(find "$carpeta" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | wc -l)
    
    [[ $_cant_respaldos -gt $_cant_respaldos_permitidos ]] \
        && ls -t "$carpeta" \
            | tail -n $((_cant_respaldos - _cant_respaldos_permitidos)) \
            | xargs -I % rm "$carpeta/%"

done
```

Nota el `$((_cant_respaldos - _cant_respaldos_permitidos))`

Comment: nótese que si un fichero tiene un salto de línea en el nombre (cosa alto improbable, lo sé), contará como dos. Por ello suele usar `find .... -print '.'`para que cada fichero cuente una sola vez.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, ¡bien resuelto!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! ya lo resolví basandome en el ejemplo de Cuauhtli!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias, fedorqui. Y @trnc, si te sirvió mi respuesta, no olvides marcarla como la correcta y/o votarla positivamente para que los que tengan dudas semejantes puedan despejar sus dudas sobre mi respuesta.